# how to load view in angular js using ui-view?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to load or open my first view using ui-view.I am not getting error but not able to show ciew here is my plunker 
http://plnkr.co/edit/kXJV11B0Bi8XV2nwMXLt

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    app.config(Routes);


    Routes.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider'];
    function Routes($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        // Default
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
        // Application
        $stateProvider
            .state('app', {
                url: '/',
                abstract: true,
                templateUrl: 'partial/firstpage.html'

            });
    }

})();
```

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/8UYvLYZMliAz31VTsv39?p=preview 
you can load view in ui-router like this

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `ui.router` dependency:

```
var app = angular.module('firstApp', ['ui.router']);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/8UYvLYZMliAz31VTsv39?p=preview) you can load view in ui-router like this

```
angular.module('firstApp',['ui.router']);

angular.module('firstApp').config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('app', {
            url:'/app',
            templateUrl: 'first.html',
        })
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('app')
});
```